# Where does Windows store amount of data read written to hard drive

Tags: windows, hard-drive

I want to develop a program which keeps track of the amount of data written to my hard drive. I searched the Internet but didn't find the necessary API calls.
But they have to exist as I found a commercial program (www.hddled.com) which does exactly what I want to achieve and it even shows the amount of data read/written when it's started way after Windows was started. Thus I strongly suppose Windows keeps itself track of this figures somewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, this sort of information is available through the Windows [Performance Counters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373083%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). In particular, the disk subsystem will publish (somewhere!) the number of bytes read and written to each disk device. Be prepared to do some digging to find exactly the information you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Physically? Probably in the file file descriptor table.

Answer (score 0):

After some further digging on the internet I found the perfect solution. It's called "Windows Management Infrastructure" and the following lines of C# code deliver the amount of read/written data during the a windows session, although the values' names are a little misleading:

```
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher =
   new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM  Win32_PerfRawData_PerfDisk_PhysicalDisk");
ManagementObjectCollection col = searcher.Get();
m.GetPropertyValue("DiskReadBytesPerSec");
m.GetPropertyValue("DiskWriteBytesPerSec");
foreach (ManagementObject m in col)
{
   m.GetPropertyValue("DiskReadBytesPerSec");
   m.GetPropertyValue("DiskWriteBytesPerSec");
}
```

Comment: These are per second. The question was about the total amount of bytes read/written.